# Proof that if a relation R is in 3NF and if every key in R is simple, then R is in BCNF?

Tags: normalization, database-theory

"*A key is simple if it consists of only one attribute*". Prove that if a relation R is in 3NF and if every key in R is simple, then R is in BCNF. Your proof should be general, e.g., it should not assume that R has a fixed number of, say two or three, attributes.

Solution:

Consider an `FD X -> Y` that holds in R. Since R is in 3NF, either

1. X is a superkey or
2. Y is a member of a key.

In the second case, since every key in R is simple, Y is itself a key, which implies that X is a superkey.
Therefore, `X -> Y` does not violate BCNF in either case, which implies that R is in BCNF.

I understand everything except the final part; Y being a key implies X being a superkey. Can somebody elaborate on that?

Comment: Where did you get these 1 and 2? They don't seem to be the definition of 3NF. Consider relation `R` with 3 attributes `ABC` and the only key being `A`. Then `BC->B` is an FD that holds but 1 or 2 are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question (I happen to be reading the Ullman book right now). I think the answer is something like this:

Assume that `X` is not a superkey. Then, each attribute in `Y` is a member of a key (is prime). Since each key consists of one attribute, `y -> {every other attribute}`, where `y` is a member of `Y`. Then by transitivity, `X -> {every other attribute}`, which implies that `X` is a superkey. We contradicted our original assumption, that `X` is not a superkey, hence `X` must be a superkey.

The most important part of the proof is the transitivity part.